# Organize subplots using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the content of a json file. The script should generate 64 subplots. Each subplot consists of 128 samples (voltage levels). "ElementSig" is a "key" in that json file for a list of 8192 samples. I am taking 128 samples at a time and generate a subplot of it as you see in my following script:

```
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
json_data = open('txrx.json')
loaded_data = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()
j = 0
E = loaded_data['ElementSig']

for i in range(64):
    plt.ylabel('E%s' % str(i+1))
    print 'E', i, ':'
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.subplot(64, 2, i+1)
    print E[0+j:127+j]
    plt.plot(E[0+j:127+j])
    j += 128
plt.show()
```

The results is very packed and the figures are overlapping.
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a better figure when I saved it as .png file.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 222))
plt.subplots_adjust(top=.9, bottom=0.1, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)

for i in range(1, 65):

    print 'E', i, ':'

    plt.subplot(64, 2, i)
    plt.ylabel('E%s' % str(i))

    i += 1
    print E[0+j:127+j]
    plt.plot(E[0+j:127+j])
    j += 128
plt.savefig('foo.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Though I believe there is a better solution.